# Best financial model to proportionally distribute the company's income to all employees?

Tags: labor-economics, economic-growth, financial-economics, wages, human-capital

I'm planning to start a project of something "innovative". And among some of the parts of the project that I'm thinking about, it's in the term of how money (profits) should be distributed.

The truth is, I personally am not a connoisseur of finance and economics at the level I desire. That's why I go to this platform.

In a nutshell, my idea is this:

Of all the capital (income) that the company receives for the sale of its products (suppose it is "coffee"), I want 30% for the company, 40% for research and development terms (in favor of improve the product and everything related to it and its services), and the remaining 30%, that is distributed among absolutely ALL those involved, from the people who collect the coffee beans (even if they are located in other latitudes, make them receive their retribution proportional), an employee like the one who is dedicated to the services of cleaning and maintenance, up to the highest positions or positions. All proportionally and depending on the value that is contributed to the company, as if each employee (no matter how small the position), was their own company.

As if each one was a shareholder of the company.

The questions are: Does this type of model exist? and more specifically, what would be the best financial model to proportionally distribute the company's income to all employees, also according to the value they contribute?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Your problem is, how do you decide how much value someone brings to the company? Until you can solve that question you will not be able to find a good solution to your issue. Some positions in the company is “easy” to measure, eg salespeople - but you cannot measure how good or bad they would perform if you change other staff, eg cleaning etc., so how will you measure their value?

Comment: Excellent question! What do you suggest for something like that? How could the "impact" of an employee be measured on the performance of the entire company?

Anyway, to clarify, if the company earns more all employees will earn more. There will be policies of flat salary rates (in the catastrophic case that the company losses money, so that the salary will be at least equal his/her position in any other company).

Comment: Your question has no objective answer.This is more related to your political orientations. E.g. you are communist ? Then, equi-distribute profits.